# How to read a person field and hence assign that user a permission role

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom

I try this code but i dont know why its failing

```
ListItem targetListItem = companylibrary.GetItemById(listItemId);

            clientContext.Load(targetListItem,x => x["Directors"]);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            // create and cast the FieldUserValue from the value 


            FieldUserValue[] fuv = (FieldUserValue[])targetListItem["Directors"];

            User user = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < fuv.Length; i++)
            {

                user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(fuv[i].LookupValue);
                clientContext.Load(user);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

//crashes here
                    subAgreements.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
                }

Comment: whats the error ? are you using person field with allow multi checked ?

Comment: @GautamSheth Yes multi checked is allowed, i cant seem to get anything in that fuv array

Comment: can you write the code in try-catch block and see the exception ?

Comment: @GautamSheth +  $exception {"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]'."} System.InvalidCastException

Comment: its means the field is not allow multi checked. Go to the column settings and change it to allow multiple values :)